# Changing IP on Domain Controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller, ip-address

I'm considering changing the IP on a 2008 Domain Controller, anything that I should be aware of to look out for?

Will be doing this on a Saturday night to, leases renew every 24 hours so by Monday morning all the machines will have valid DHCP leases with correct DNS servers. Have a list of all machines on static IP so I know to update them while I'm at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely change the IP address on a domain controller, just be sure to reboot it to ensure proper updating of DNS records and that all services running on the machine correctly acknowledge the change.

If the server is also running the DNS service you should be careful to update client settings, but looking at your question it looks like you've already taken this into account :-)

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory finds it resources via DNS resource records. So changing the IP shouldn't cause problems. After changing the IP address; go into CMD mode and type`ipconfig /registerdns` Just remember to change its subnet in 'Sites and Services' to reflect the new IP address.

Comment: ipconfig /registerdns will not suffice, it will only register A and PTR records for the server; the actual SRV resource records are populated upon restarting Active Directory services.

Answer (score 0):

I have only done this with 2003, but:

- If this is a new subnet, don't forget sites and services like Jake Mentioned.
- Also, I ran into a catch-22 with the DNS IP.  If it is configured to listen on a specific IP, make sure  you change that in the DNS settings before changing the IP of the machine.  If you don't, when you reboot DNS will fail, and you won't be able to change the settings on DNS either. There might be away around this, but this is what happened to me with the standard DNS console in 2003. I just gave the machine a secondary IP of the old IP so I could get into the DNS settings to add the new one, then removed the secondary IP when I was done.

Answer (score -3):

Providing the DC isn't hosting any of the FSMO roles and isn't your sole DC, you might be better off demoting, changing the IP address and re-promoting it to ensure you don't end up with the old IP address anywhere.

Should on take 10-20 mins to do:

- DCPromo - demote
- Change IP address
- DCPromo - promote

This way you can be sure the old IP address isn't anywhere in AD or DNS.

Comment: That's totally unnecessary and a lot more invasive than simply changing the IP address.

Comment: @Massimo - I disagree I don't think you can be too cautious with Domain Controllers.  Running De-promo/Promo really isn't a big deal - I always prefer a totally "clean" DC.

Comment: "I don't think you can be too cautious with Domain Controllers"... right. That's *exactly* why I'd avoid promoting them back and forth unless absolutely needed.